# Performance boost on rendering in react

Tags: reactjs, performance, user-interface, onclick

I am building a react app and am essentially enlarging and placing a border around an image when it is clicked. The code below is in a Modal component that exists for each item in a product list. At a time there will be no more than 6-8 images being rendered within the modal. I find however that when I test with just one image it is much faster and doesn't lag as much as when I have 4 images when I open the modal. Thus, I am wondering if there is a performance advantage for either of the two sections of code for doing the same thing below or if there is a better way to do this:

call to initialize the modal

```
 <ProductModal
          show={this.state.isModalOpen}
          onHide={() => this.setState({ isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen })}
          item={this.state.currentItem}
          key={this.state.currentItem.id}
        />
```

**Implementation 1:**

inside render() of ProductModal:

```
<div className="d-flex flex-wrap mt-5 align-self-start ml-3">
              {this.props.item.images.map((image, index) => {
                if (index >= maxSelectableImages) {
                  return null;
                } else {
                  return (
                    <img
                      className={`selectable-image ${
                        index === 0 ? "selected-border" : ""
                      }`}
                      alt="Error Loading"
                      src={image}
                      key={index}
                      onClick={(e) => this.updateSelectedImage(e, image)}
                    ></img>
                  );
                }
              })}
            </div>
```

onclick handler:

```
      updateSelectedImage(event, image) {
        if (this.state.prevSelectedElement) {
          this.state.prevSelectedElement.classList.remove("selected-border");
        } else {
          // if there is no prevSelected element then by default the selected item
          // always is the first image in the array as seen in the above snippet from render
          **// but this means for each modal I have to call query selector once**
          const firstImage = document.getElementsByClassName("selected-border")[0];
          firstImage.classList.remove("selected-border");
        }
        event.target.classList.add("selected-border");
        this.setState({ selectedImage: image, prevSelectedElement: event.target });
      }
```

**Implementation 2:**

in render():

```
<div className="d-flex flex-wrap mt-5 align-self-start ml-3">
{this.props.item.images.map((image, index) => {
  if (index >= maxSelectableImages) {
    return null;
  } else if (index === 0) {
    const firstItem =  (
      <img
        className="selectable-image selected-border"
        alt="Error Loading"
        src={image}
        key={index}
        onClick={(e) => this.updateSelectedImage(e, image)}
      ></img>
    );
    **// is this dangerous? I have read it can cause infinite loops to call set state in render.**
    this.setState({prevSelectedElement: firstItem});
    return firstItem;
  } else {
      return ( 
      <img
        className="selectable-image"
        alt="Error Loading"
        src={image}
        key={index}
        onClick={(e) => this.updateSelectedImage(e, image)}
      ></img>
      );
  }
})}
</div>
```

handler:

```
  updateSelectedImage(event, image) {
  **// notice no query selector call needed now**
    this.state.prevSelectedElement.classList.remove("selected-border");
    event.target.classList.add("selected-border");
    this.setState({ selectedImage: image, prevSelectedElement: event.target });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
this.setState({prevSelectedElement: firstItem});
```

You are not supposed to use `setState()` within `render()` because `setState()` can trigger re-rendering if the state is changed. In your case it would trigger at least one more time. 
You also should not put react elements like `firstItem` into state.

Try to separate you logic from rendering. You should use `selectedIndex` and `prevSelectedIndex` instead of elements.

```
onClick={() => this.updateSelectedImage(index)}
```

and

```
updateSelectedImage(index) {
    const prev= this.state.selectedIndex;
    this.setState({ selectedIndex: index, prevSelectedIndex: prev});
}
```

Comment: I am a little confused by the solution I don't see how it can help in my case. In my state object, selectedImage is a image path that is used as the src. And prevSelectedElement is the DOM node needed to remove the class "selected-border" from its class list. How can I get access to the class list for the image node from just the index?